# Closing a client socket , after server has already closed it's side

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock

(`Winsock32` / `C++` / `Win32` environment)

To my understanding, as opposed to closing a file handle for instance (using `CloseHandle()`), 
closing a socket is an operation of 2 parts, other then releasing the `SOCK` handle, and freeing the actual resource, it also responsible of informing the other side of the connection upon session termination.

The question is, how to handle the scenario of a server closing the connection for it's own reason ,  and then client trying to close it on their side. That means, how to do only the resources releasing part, as described above , without the termination informing.

Comment: It's a network - there is always going to be the possibility that a server and client my both close the connection in an overlapped fashion.  At either end, close the handle and just deal with any error/exception that might be raised during the close.

Comment: @MartinJames you're right of course , but closing a `SOCK` handle is done with `closesocket()` according to MSDN, and in the described case it  just ***blocks***

Comment: We may have an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) over here.

Answer (score 0):

> how to handle the scenario of a server closing the connection for it's
>   own reason ?

If you call `closesocket()` on a socket that have already been invalidated by a closed connection, you are just releasing the socket descriptor, you don't have to worry whether the socket is closed on the other side or not.

Comment: I don't. the problem is when `closesocket()` *blocks* in such a scenario.

Comment: @JimLanflte `closesocket()` is not blocking unless the socket's options `l_onoff` and `l_linger` are both non null, in which case it waits the specified time to allow queued data to be sent. If your program hangs indefinitely then you may have another issue in your code.

Comment: I would suggest adding `shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH)` before calling the closesocket, but if the other end has already closed their end I'm not sure if would make much of a difference.

Comment: @icabod Using `shutdown()` before `closesocket()` is a good practice to ensure that all data is sent and received on a connected socket before it is closed, hence avoiding a *hard* close. But it will only *disable* reception and/or transmission and will have no effect on an already invalid socket.